What software can I use to print multiple short blog stories with photos at the end of each?
Over the past 12 years, I take photos and do an email blog of the adventure, then email it to a wide variety of friends. So I have archived hundreds of these adventures and by wide demand, I have been told I should create a book of adventures, most likely not to sell but for myself and select friends. Each of these blogs have 20+/- color photos of 200kb to 500kb each totaling somewhere between 4mb and 10mb.
I am looking for software that I can use to print multiple short blog stories with photos at the end of the story, then with the capability of starting another story of similar size, and so on.
Is this possible? I have MS Office Professional but it does not do well with photos so this is why I am looking for a specific software that can handle both without issue.

We have a site for software recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, and the people on our graphic design site might have some ideas: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

If you want to layout a high quality print book there is no way around a dedicated desktop publishing software such as Adobe InDesign. These are easy to use and allow you to create every possible page layout imaginable. You'll also need a raster graphics editor such as Adobe Photoshop or Affinity Photo to format your images for printing.
If you are happy with a possibly mediocre end result and willing to struggle a lot with forcing the software to do the layout you envision, word processors such as Microsoft Word or Apple Pages do handle photos, but you need to make sure in the settings that the images are included in the output file in the appropriate format. Word and Pages resize your images, if you don't want to pay for something like Adobe Photoshop or Affinity Photo, but the quality isn't the best.
If you are comfortable and familiar with TeX or LaTeX, you can use these to create a professional level print-ready output file.
Whichever software you use, talk to your printer about file specs before (!) you start the layout process.

You mention Affinity Photo, I mention Affinity Publisher, the desktop publishing package from the same stable.
